# get CameraManager in Foreground Sevice

Tags: android

I try to build a Webcam, using a old Android phone Camera. To keep the process always alive I want to use a ForegroundService to take pictures and send it via ftp to a server. Notification is done, permission in Manifest are declared. However ..
When I try to get the CameraManager in the method openCamera() from the Service I get NPE and the app close.
*NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference*

When I try the same out of the MainActivity it works.
Can someone help me to solve this problem? would be cool, thx.

public class CamService extends Service {

```
private static final String TAG = "CamService";
public static final String STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION = "START_CAM";
public static final String STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION = "STOP_CAM";
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";
public static final String CAMERA_ID = "CAMERA_ID";

private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
private static final int IMAGE_CAPTUR_CODE = 1001;
public static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;

final Handler zeitHandler = new Handler();

private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
private Size imageDiamention;


private String cameraId;
private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
;
private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
private CaptureRequest captureRequest;
private CaptureRequest.Builder getCaptureRequestBuilder;
private TextureView textureView;

private Size imageDimension;
private ImageReader imageReader;
private File file;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

TextView textView;              //als dummmy 


public CamService() { 
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "CamServise triggert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i(TAG, "CamService triggered");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        cameraId = intent.getStringExtra(cameraId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "CamServise started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "CamService started");

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CamServise stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "CamService stopped");
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelfResult(startId);
    }

    //damit wird die Notification für den Foreground service activiert
    //https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)  //war das Original
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);



    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
//---------------end of onStart()-----------------------------------------------

//---------------takePicture()--------------------------------------------------
public void takePicture() throws CameraAccessException {
    startBackgroundThread();


    if (cameraDevice == null) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "no cameraDevice --> return");
        Log.i(TAG, "no cameraDevice");
        Log.i(TAG, "no cameraDevice start openCamera()");
        openCamera();
        Log.i(TAG, "no cameraDevice openCamera() done");
        return;
    }

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
    Size[] jpegSizes = null;
    jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0) {
        width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
        height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
    }
    ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
    List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
    outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
    outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
    outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    //int rotation = getWindowmanager().geDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    //captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();
    file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/new" + ts + ".jpg");
    Log.i(TAG, "file angelegt");
    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image image = null;
            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            try {
                save(bytes);
                Log.i(TAG, "save bytes");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {       //warum zweites 5, 5:12
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (image != null) {
                    image.close();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);  //5,6:23
}
//-----------------------end takePicture()-------------------------------------------

//-----------------------save file---------------------------------------------------
private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    outputStream.write(bytes);
    outputStream.close();
}
//-----------------------end of save()-----------------------------------------------

//-----------------------CameraDevice.Callcack---------------------------------------
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice = camera;
        try {
            createCameraPreview();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
};
//-------------------------end of Callback---------------------------------------

//-------------------------creatCameraèrevue()-----------------------------------
private void createCameraPreview() throws CameraAccessException {
    SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDiamention.getWidth(), imageDiamention.getHeight());
    //texture.setDefaultBufferSize(640,320);              //
    Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
    captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            if (cameraDevice == null) return;
            cameraCaptureSession = session;

            try {
                updatePreview();
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "config changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, null);
}
//----------------------------end of cameraPreView--------------------------------------------

//----------------------------updadatePrevue()------------------------------------------------
private void updatePreview() throws CameraAccessException {
    if (cameraDevice == null) return;
    captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
}
//--------------------------end  of updatePreview---------------------------------------------

//--------------------------openCamera()-------------------------------------------------------
private void openCamera() throws CameraAccessException {

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    Log.i(TAG, "CameraId = " + cameraId);

    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
    //Log.i(TAG, "CameraCharacteristics = "+characteristics);

    StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
    imageDiamention = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
}

//-----------------------------end of openCamera---------------------------------------------

//----------------------------start Background()---------------------------------------------
private void startBackgroundThread() {

    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Backgrpund");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}

protected void stopBackgroundThread() throws InterruptedException {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    mBackgroundThread.join();
    mBackgroundThread = null;
    mBackgroundHandler = null;
}
//-----------------------------stop Background ---------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        stopBackgroundThread();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems to call `takePicture()` in your [mcve]. Make `takePicture()` be `private`, and only call it from inside the `CamService`, sometime after `onCreate()` on the `CamService` completes.

Comment: thx for your replay, the idea was to call takePicture() via onlick method in MainActivity for test purposes. later it will be called within a timer inside the Service. the problem is to get the CameraManager by calling getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE). this works in the MainActivity, but not in the CamService where it ends with NPE. Thats the problem, if you have an idea why ??

Comment: "the idea was to call takePicture() via onlick method in MainActivity for test purposes" -- most likely, your code for doing this is incorrect. For example, perhaps you are trying to create an instance of `CamService` directly, which will not work.

Comment: thank you very much, indeed, the NPE came from calling takePicture() directly out off MainActivity. Via Intent it works. I will clean the code and put it entirely. But the headline is misleading now because it wasn't the problem. maybe it is better to delete the thread. thx and kind regards.